# symfony2 form: how to save entity and how to add more then one entity to the same form?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, formbuilder

I have this function in a entitytype class

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        //...other controls
        ->add('types', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'MyApplicationBundle:Type',
            'property' => 'type',
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => true))
        ->add('save', 'submit');
}
```

the archive entity has a type property, many to may relation

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Type", mappedBy="archives")
 **/
private $types;
```

the type entity has a archives property on the other side

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Archive", inversedBy="types")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="types_archives")
 **/
private $archives;
```

the form is correctly displayed with a select multiple control but I'm only able to save in the archive table, not in the types_archives table. Any idea on how to fix?
also, can I add more then one entity to the same type?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If just one side of relations saved in database try to do following steps:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        //...other controls
        ->add('types', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'MyApplicationBundle:Type',
            // This makes form call setter method on related entity
            'by_reference' => false,
            'allow_add' => true,
            'allow_delete' => true,
            'property' => 'type',
            'expanded' => false,
            'multiple' => true))
        ->add('save', 'submit');
}
```

in `Archive` entity:

```
public function addType(Type $type){
    $this->types[] = $type;
    $type->addArchive($this);
}

public function removeType(Type $type){
    $this->types->removeElement($type);
    $type->setArchive(null);
}
```

I hope this helps about first part of your question.

For the second part you can use `collection` type check out following link:

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html

Comment: thanks for your reply. it works on insert but not on update. I mean if the first time I choose, ex, opt1 and opt2, is fine. if later on update I only choose opt3, I'll have opt1, opt2 and opt3 saved.

Comment: thanks for your help, it works perfectly. I just had to add a setArchive method in my Entity\Type class, I don't know why doctrine:generate:entities didn't create it, anyway now works, thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Here are some directions that I would give you.
1. To save the related entities, try reading about "cascade persist" if you are using doctrine for example.
2. To have multiple entities on the form, read about "class composition". A composite object which you will set as the form's "data class" will allow you contain multiple entity objects.